# BERT Encoder layer is non-trainable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine-tune a BERT model from TensorFlow hub. I loaded the preprocessing layer and the encoder as follow :

```
bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_preprocess/3')
bert_model = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1')
```

And this is my model definition :

```
def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(bert_preprocess_model, name='preprocessing')
  encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
  encoder = hub.KerasLayer(bert_model, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
  outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooled_output']
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='classifier')(net)
  return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)

classifier_model = build_classifier_model()
```

But I get the following error : ERROR:absl:hub.KerasLayer is trainable but has zero trainable weights.
In the official website, the model is fine-tunable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, simply add trainable = True :

```
bert_model = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1',trainable=True)
```